# React-native «exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64» on M1 silicon

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, apple-m1

Environment - Mac m1 2020, OS Ventura 13.5.1, system default jdk version 20.0.2, react-native version 71.8

android -> gradle-> cradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

Steps to reproduce:

run  **yarn android**

Error:
**exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64**

If I am trying upgrade version of gradle, then get another error:

**Kotlin version issues: The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0. Not working by changing the version in build.gradle**

How to run android successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

We need change java version for compatibility with Gradle and Kotlin:

Check default system java in terminal:

**java -version**

Check list existing java:

**/usr/libexec/java_home -V**

Then try:

1. change  for one terminal process(because if you close terminal and open new, java version will return to system default), run:
   **export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.20`**

And after that run **yarn android** in the same terminal

2. set default system Java version:
    open profile config file zsh or bash

**open ~/.bash_profile**

And change default Java version:

**export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.2`** (or any version what you need from already installed Javas list)

**Build successful!**

Good luck!